# ECDSA: invalid signature length error while, when using the signature provided by remix ide

Tags: hash, ethereum, solidity, remix, openzeppelin

i am signing messsage in remix ide, and am trying to verify the signature and data as below

```
  bytes32 hashInput=keccak256(bytes(temp));
        bytes memory signature=bytes("0x975ff3abe5c7df0e95ab76f308f5b73ca0b803f1c7d74d44098bc75c6efd845c7908ff2b2e4b1a9bee653237475e59d17c13634042e4759154e70618850aa89e1c");
        emit test(signature);
        bytes32 h=ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(hashInput);
        address  _signer=ECDSA.recover(h,signature);
```

temp is coming in arguments of function, this is message that I signed earlier. now the signature length error is troubling me. i am using ecdsa from openzepplien

Comment: Have you encountered the solution?

Comment: @RenanCoelho i left this field 